# Combine like values from rows and concatenate subsequent columns

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a problem that I am sure is probably pretty basic, but my brain has quit functioning, and I can't get past this.  I have a table with two columns.  An ID column and a Service column.  Shown below:

[image]

As you can see, the ID column has duplicate values, I would like to combine the duplicates in the ID column and then concatenate the Service column for each row as shown below:

[image]

ANy help would be GREATLY appreciated!!!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Do you want a solution using DAX or Power Query? Please upload sample data as copiable text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In the query editor go to `Group by`

[image]

This throws an error. Now edit the code line above from

`= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, {{"Column3", each List.Sum([Column2]), type nullable text}})`

to

`= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, {{"Column3", each Text.Combine([Column2], ", "), type nullable text}})`

and you will get:

[image]